# What do you call it when doctors or therapists give the same prescriptions or solutions to everyone that has similar illnesses or problems?

Tags: phrase-requests

As in, they do not attempt to give individualized prescriptions. What's a phrase or word that characterizes this tendency?

Comment: Do the solutions cure the patients?

Comment: @Gandalf the solutions may or may not work

Comment: If they don't work, it's _quackery_; if they _do_ work, it's a good diagnosis.

Comment: Western medicine.

Comment: "Cookie-cutter" is an adjective often applied to repeated application of the same technique.

Comment: Roundup? Monsantoism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither of these are specific to medical practice, but you could call this "a shotgun approach" to the problem, or a "one size fits all" solution.

Comment: 'one size fits all' sounds good to me.

Answer (score 1):

If a doctor gives all his patients the same prescription, there are only two possibilities:  either all their patients have the same disease and need the same treatment, which is a coincidence, or it's just charlatanism or quackery.  If the treatment does any harm, then it's also malpractice. The term you are looking for may be **"a ready-made prescription"**.

> - "Dr X seems to have ready-made prescriptions.  All his patients are on Aspirin and Atorvastatin."

It can also be used in other contexts: "I'm sorry but we don't have a ready-made presciption to beat inflation."

Comment: Thank you, this is a good one, I'll upvote when I get my votes back. I still like 'one size fits all' slightly better as it's more idiomatic

Comment: @V0ight  I don't understand "when I get my votes back".  I agree with you "a one-size-fits-all approach" is more idiomatic.

Comment: I used up my 40 votes for the day

Comment: @V0ight  Boy, you are more than generous.